# react PureRenderMixin alternatives?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to adopt `shallowEqual` and one way is to use PureRenderMixin.

But I'm trying to stay away from javascript `mixins` (
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html)

I'm also using redux, and redux's `connect` gives the pure render functionality already.  (which means redux connect is the HOC which provides pure-render)

So I can just connect components that needs pure-render, but I also read the distinction between dumb / smart components, and reluctant to `connect` every components.

Should I just use `connect` ? or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `React.PureComponent`.

```
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
       ...
    }
}
```

([React Top-Level API](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html))

For an alternative, you can use the legacy [shallow-compare addon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-shallow-compare) but it will require you to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` in every component.

You should migrate your code to ES6 classes, `createClass` has been deprecated.

Comment: Oh. I'm using `createClass` , wouldn't it be a big change ?

Comment: @eugene `createClass` is deprecated but it isn't a big change really. The conversion is simple.

Answer (score 0):

Declarative way of using `PureRenderMixin` is to use the `@PureRender` attribute at the top of your reactJs class as shown in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734881/what-is-purerender-attribute-for-a-reactjs-component):

```
@PureRender
export default class UiWidget extends Component {
}
```