# What is @PureRender attribute for a reactJs component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cam across the definition of a component in the code base I'm working upon:

```
@PureRender
export default class UiWidget extends Component {
}
```

I tried googling to understand the significance of the attribute `@PureRender` which has been used to decorate the component but didn't get any relevant link. Can someone help me understand the impact of applying this attribute on a reactJs component?

Comment: I think its related to JS pure function : given the same props and state, the render function will produce the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three ways to define a react component:

1. Functional stateless component which doesn't extend any class
2. A component that extends `PureComponent` class
3. A normal component that extends `Component` class

For simple, presentation-only components that need to be easily reused, stateless functional components are preferred.

`PureComponent` overrides the `shouldComponentUpdate` for you and re-renders the component only if the props or state have actually changed. The important point here is it only does a **shallow comparison** of nextProps and nextState. You can read more [here](http://aeflash.com/2015-02/react-tips-and-best-practices.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084515/how-does-shallow-compare-work-in-react). `@PureRender` is simply the declarative way of saying that my reactJs component inherits from predefined `PureComponent` reactJs component.

Extending `Component` class helps to implement your own `shouldComponentUpdate` if you need some performance gains by performing you custom comparison logic between next/current props and state.

Comment: So decorating a custom component (which inherits from `Component`) with `@PureRender` attribute and a component which inherits from `PureComponent` defined in reactJs library is one and the same thing. Is it? Can you please share some details about `@PureRender` attribute in your post which is my primary question.

Comment: Yes. it is one and the same thing. You can look at an example here https://github.com/brigand/react-purerender

Answer (score 3):

This is a javascript [decorator](http://tc39.github.io/proposal-decorators/), originally proposed in ES2016 (ES7). I believe they were removed from the proposal and postponed.

The purpose of the decorator is to add `shouldComponentUpdate` implementation with shallow property comparison.

Nowadays the same is done using extension from `PureComponent`:

```
export default class UiWidget extends React.PureComponent
```

I believe the decorator is not part of `React`, therefore it is probably implemented somewhere in your project, or in a dependency, similar to 
[pure-render-decorator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pure-render-decorator).

Historically, `React` implemented that using `pure-render-mixin`, however mixins couldn't be used with ES6 classes (only with `React.createClass`) therefore alternative solutions were introduced. Decorators were one of them.